# how to merge xml files with root attributes?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have several xml files, and they all have attributes in root.

More or less this way:

**FILE1.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<item_root id="item01" name="Item 01">
    <child>content 01</child>
</item_root>
```

**FILE2.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<item_root id="item02" name="Item 02">
    <child>content 02</child>
</item_root>
```

... and so on.

I need to merge all the files in one, dynamically with php.
But as a result of what I'm doing, I can't get the root attributes.
The result looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<itens>
  <item_root>
    <child>content 01</child>
  </item_root>
  <item_root>
    <child>content 02</child>
  </item_root>
</itens>
```

But it should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<itens>
  <item_root id="item01" name="Item 01">
    <child>content 01</child>
  </item_root>
  <item_root id="item02" name="Item 02">
    <child>content 02</child>
  </item_root>
</itens>
```

My merge code looks like this:

```
<?php
    $files= array(
      'xmlitens/file1.xml',
      'xmlitens/file2.xml'
    );
    
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $itens = $dom->createElement('itens');
    
    foreach ($files as $filename) {
      $fileaddDom = new DOMDocument();
      $fileaddDom->load($filename);
        $itemroot = $dom->createElement('item_root');
      if ($fileaddDom->documentElement) {
        foreach ($fileaddDom->documentElement->childNodes as $node) {
          $itemroot->appendChild(
            $dom->importNode($node, TRUE)
          );
        }
      }
      $itens->appendChild($itemroot);
    }
    $dom->appendChild($itens);
?>
```

Is there an easy method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

After I posted the question, the answer miraculously appeared to me.

Here is the solution I found:

```
$files= array(
  'xmlitens/file1.xml',
  'xmlitens/file2.xml'
);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$itens = $dom->createElement('itens');

foreach ($files as $filename) {
  $fileaddDom = new DOMDocument();
  $fileaddDom->load($filename);

  //This is the line that solves everything.
  $node = $fileaddDom->getElementsByTagName("item_root")->item(0);

  if ($fileaddDom->documentElement) {
     $itens->appendChild( $dom->importNode($node, true) );
  }
}
$dom->appendChild($itens);

Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print_r($dom->saveXML());
```